# String format is not valid in addthis_widget.js file

Tags: javascript, addthis

I have used `addthis_widget.js` file in my project it working fine but when I open the browser 
Error console I got the below error in Error Console:

```
Timestamp: 7/26/2013 10:19:00 AM Error: InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character Source File: http://s7.addthis.com/static/r07/sh69.html# Line: 2
```

Comment: This is likely a problem with how you included addthis. Can you post example code to jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Are you still getting this error?  If so, where are you located and what browser are you using?

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply, In Firefox Error Console I got it ,Now it's resolved I have updated addthis_widget.js file so now it's working fine